# ListView without children right after "setAdapter" is called

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I reset the adapter of my ListView as seen here:

```
ListView lvPlayerStrip = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvPlayerStrips);
lvPlayerStrip.setAdapter(stripAdapter);
```

And right after that I want to get a View out of the ListView like so:

```
int wantedPosition = position;
int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() - listView.getHeaderViewsCount();
int wantedChild = wantedPosition - firstPosition;

return listView.getChildAt(wantedChild);
```

My problem is, that there are no childs of my ListView at that given moment. The getView method of my adpater isn't called at that point.

I searched for methods of ListView to generate all Views, without success. I tried .notifyDataSetChanged on my adapter and .invalidateViews on my ListView. But the getView method is still called AFTER I try to get the child :/

Comment: And you're absolutely sure, there is items in your `adapter`? What does `stripAdapter.getCount()` return? And what kind of `Adapter` implementation are you using? `ArrayAdapter` or something else?

Comment: why do you want to access a view that has not yet inflated?